# Trying to scrape substrings within paragraphs using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Main questions I have:

- RegEx practices for statements that are close but not similar iterated through a list of websites when dealing with doubles and text
- Should I pull all of the text then parse out what I want in the following code? Or is there a better way?

I am currently trying to extract interest rate data from different lenders using regular expression. I want to use regex because I want to be able to add more URLs as more lenders arise. I want the extracted information to basically take on the form of:

x.xx% - xx.xx% (the low - high bands of the interest rates)

Most of the websites vary in how they present this, some examples:

- APR ranges from x.xx% to xx.xx%
- Rates range from x.xx% to xx.xx%
- x.xx% - xx.xx%
- range from x.xx% (AA) to xx.xx% (HR)

Currently I am trying to just grab the paragraph the text lives in and then make substrings off of that to create the final piece of information I need (x.xx% - xx.xx%). Not sure if this is the best method, but would like to crowdsource my issue.

```
plcompetitors = ['https://www.lendingclub.com/loans/personal-loans',
                'https://www.marcus.com/us/en/personal-loans',
                'https://www.discover.com/personal-loans/',
                'https://www.lightstream.com/',
                'https://www.prosper.com/']

#cycle through links in array until it finds APR rates/fixed or variable using regex
for link in plcompetitors:
    l = r.get(link)
    l.encoding = 'utf-8'
    data = l.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')
    paragraph = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('% APR'))
#using this next if statement to try and iterate through what turned up empty in the initial pass through with the first .compile statement
    if paragraph == []:
        paragraph = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('% - [0-9]'))
    print(paragraph)
```

Which returns this:

```
[]
[]
[' 6.99% to 24.99% APR']
['\r\n                    Payment example: Monthly payments for a $10,000 loan at 3.09% APR with a term of 3 years would result in 36 monthly payments of $291.21.', 'The lender’s interest rate (APR) must not be supported by any third-party arrangements such as vehicle manufacturer subvention payments (with rates as low as 0.0% APR), other manufacturer discounts, rate buy-downs by car buying services or any other\n      similar third-party subsidized rate offerings.']
['* For example, a three-year $10,000 loan with a Prosper Rating of AA would have an interest rate of 5.31% and a 2.41% origination fee for an annual percentage rate (APR) of 6.95% APR. You would receive $9,759 and make 36 scheduled monthly payments of $301.10. A five-year $10,000 loan with a Prosper Rating of A would have an interest rate of 8.39% and a 5.00% origination fee with a 10.59% APR. You would receive $9,500 and make 60 scheduled monthly payments of $204.64. Origination fees vary between 2.41%-5%. APRs through Prosper range from 6.95% (AA) to 35.99% (HR) for first-time borrowers, with the lowest rates for the most creditworthy borrowers. Eligibility for loans up to $40,000 depends on the information provided by the applicant in the application form. Eligibility is not guaranteed, and requires that a sufficient number of investors commit funds to your account and that you meet credit and other conditions. Refer to Borrower Registration Agreement for details and all terms and conditions. All loans made by WebBank, member FDIC.']
```

Comment: So, what are the key _substrings_  you need to search for ? Be exact, but it can be slightly variable . All the samples are required and repeatable.

Comment: The key substrings are the two doubles (percentages) I want the high and low interest rates that are posted on the site. If I could pull those two I could manipulate them on a spreadsheet that will be the final export.